# Copying my Blockchain account to Multibit

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

Please can you tell me if it is possible to transfer my Blockchain account to Mulitibit.I want to keep my bitcoin address but back it up on Multibit.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the export section on blockchain.info. This will provide you with your private key(s) so you can then import them on Multibit.

If you go to the "import/export" tab there will be an option to export your private-keys for every address in your wallet. There is also an import function that allows you to import a private-key into your blockchain.info wallet. You can click on export unencrypted and it will display your public and private-keys in a JSON output. The long string of what seems to be random characters after the "priv" is actually your private-key. The string of characters after the "addr" is your address. As you can see in my example there is more than one key exported. If you wanted to you could copy the private-key and then import it into another wallet program. This would allow you to access this address from more than one wallet service.

[image: Exporting Keys on Blockchain.info]

**Never show anyone your private-keys.
I am only showing these keys for demonstration purposes.**

Comment: How do you then transfer it to Multi bit as there does not seem to be an option to import private keys on that

Comment: There is an import private key with multibit classic, so I assume you are using the new hierarchical deterministic multibit (Multibit HD)? These are two different types of key management methods. With multibit HD it uses seeds which then creates new addresses based on that seed. Whereas blockchain.info and multibit classic uses single address management.  So in otherwords, you won't be able to use multibit HD to back up blockchain.info, single addresses. You'll need to use electrum or switch to multibit classic.